# When to use chomp?

Tags: perl, chomp

What is the purpose and advantages of chomp function.
What all can it do? 
Does using chomp creates any problems? 
or using chomp after file opening is necessary?

Comment: This is like Perl 101...

Comment: What is wrong with the [documentation for chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

chomp is used to remove the `$/` variable which is set to mostly `\n` (new line).

```
$/ is the input record separator, newline by default.
```

> [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html): It returns the total number of characters removed from all its
>   arguments. It's often used to remove the newline from the end of an
>   input record.

Answer (score 7):

`chomp` simply removes the newline (actually `$/`) from the end of a string if it is there. It's useful when reading lines from a file (for example) where you want the newline gone, but can still be used on strings that don't have the newline.

It's basically similar to:

```
chop if /\n$/;
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

`chomp` removes the newline characters (if any) from the end of a line of text.  It is useful because, then you don't have to worry about the particular way that your input represents newlines--Perl handles the details for you.

When should you use it?  Whenever you need to remove trailing newlines!  Reading data from a text file is the most common case.